# Print media queries using less.css loop

Tags: css, less

I'm using less.css as css preprocessor, and i was wonder if it is possible to print out media queries using less.css loops.

I've tried a very basic example loop:

```
@iterations: 30;
.loopingClass (@index) when (@index > 0) {

    (~".myclass_@{index}") {
        font-size: -@index px;
    }

    .loopingClass(@index - 1);
}
.loopingClass (0) {}
.loopingClass (@iterations);
```

but this will end up creating a class.
According to this example:

http://codepen.io/ericrasch/pen/HzoEx?editors=110

we can create media queries in less using this syntax:

```
@mobile:      ~"only screen and (max-width: 529px)";
body {
  @media @mobile {
    background: orange;
    content: "mobile";
  }
}
```

But, as you can see, the media query value is a variable and not a class. So my question is, can i use less.css loop to print out media queries value as variable instead of classes? Or there's any workaround for this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This - *print out media queries value as variable instead of classes* - seems a bit of a XY problem to me. Not sure why you want media queries to be output as a variable. Outputting media queries through loops is possible. Could you show us what is the CSS that you are expecting?

Comment: I think you are probably trying to do something like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879271/is-there-a-less-equivalent-to-this-sass-functionality/28879571#28879571).

Comment: Yes! exactly like this! thank you very much @harry!